# What query string can I use to enable web part editing?

Tags: web-part

This is a real long-shot, but here goes.

I followed this tutorial: httpcode.msdn.microsoft.comAdding-default-web-parts-ab7aec72#content

And successfully, have incorporated the server control into my page layouts mentioned in order to define a 'default' web part for the web part zone defined on my page layout.

The one problem I'm having is that when a user chooses to add a 'New Page' and then chooses the page layout in question - the web part zones are not actually in edit mode (despite the fact that the query strings *do* define ControlMode as Edit and DisplayMode as Design).

The one way I've found around this is to append &ToolPaneView=3 onto the query string - but as you may know - this then displays the 'Add Web Parts' dialog - and this isn't something that fits the spec.

If anyone knows of any other ways I can taket he user to a display mode were the web part zones are automatically editable I'd *really really* appreciate it.

EDIT: I've also tried the Contents=1 parameter, with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code i've used before to make a page layout editable only when being displayed in a modal.  You should be able to get what you need from it:

```
        function ChangeToEditMode(){
            if (window.location.search.match("[?&]PageView=Shared")){
                var inDesignMode = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode.value; 

                if (inDesignMode == "1") 
                { 
                    // page is in edit mode 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1, null); 
                } 
            }
            else{
                if (document.forms["aspnetForm"]["MSOLayout_InDesignMode"] != null) 
                    document.forms["aspnetForm"]["MSOLayout_InDesignMode"].value = 1;
                if (document.forms["aspnetForm"]["MSOAuthoringConsole_FormContext"] != null) 
                    document.forms["aspnetForm"]["MSOAuthoringConsole_FormContext"].value = 1;
                if (document.forms["aspnetForm"]["MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName"] != null) 
                    document.forms["aspnetForm"]["MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName"].value = "Design";
                ChangeLayoutMode(false);                
            }
        }


        if (window.location.search.match("[?&]IsDlg=1")) {
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ChangeToEditMode, "sp.js");
        }
```